# Why is this script so slow in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, optimization

I have written a script that trains a 1D Kohonen network in MATLAB and it works as a charm. I then tried to translate it to **Python 2.7**, a language in which I'm pretty new, and the script is taking forever to run.

I'll explain what I'm doing to see if someone here can throw some light on the matter. I have a given dataset in the matrix `y` and I want to train different SOMs with it. The SOM is one-dimensional (a line), and its number of neurons varies. I train a SOM of size `N=2` at first, and `N=NMax` at last, giving a total of `NMax-2+1` SOMs. For each SOM, I want to store the weights once the training is over before moving on to the next SOM.

In MATLAB, for `NMax = 5` and `iterMax = 50`, it takes 9.74 seconds. In Python, 54.04 seconds. This difference is huge, and the actual datasets, number of SOMs and number of iterations is even greater, so the Python code takes forever to end.

My current code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import time
y = np.random.rand(2500,3) # Create random dataset to test
def A(d,s): # Neighborhood function
    return np.exp(-d**2 / (2*s**2))
sigma_0 = float(5) # Initial standard deviation for A
eta_0 = float(1) # Initial learning rate
iterMax = 250 # Maximum number of iterations
NMax = 10 # Maximum number of neurons
w = range(NMax - 1) # Initialize the size of the weight matrix (it will store NMax-2+1 sets of weights, each of varying size depending on the value of N)
#%% KOHONEN 1D
t = time.time() # Start time
for N in np.arange(2,NMax + 1): # Size of the network
    w[N - 2] = np.random.uniform(0,1,(N,np.size(y,axis=1))) - 0.5 # Initial weights
    iterCount = 1; # Iteration counter
    while iterCount < iterMax:
        # Mix the datapoints to choose them in random order
        mixInputs = y[np.random.permutation(np.size(y,axis = 0)),:]
        # Decrease the value of the variance and the learning rate
        sigma = sigma_0 - (sigma_0/(iterMax + 1)) * iterCount
        eta = eta_0 - (eta_0/(iterMax + 1)) * iterCount
        for kk in range(np.size(mixInputs,axis = 0)): # Picking one datapoint at a time
            selectedInput = mixInputs[kk,:]
            # These two lines calculate the weight that is the nearest to the datapoint selected
            aux = np.absolute(np.array(np.kron(np.ones((N,1)),selectedInput)) - np.array(w[N - 2]))
            aux = np.sum(np.abs(aux)**2,axis=-1)
            ii = np.argmin(aux) # The node ii is the winner
            for jj in range(N):
                dist = min(np.absolute(ii-jj) , np.absolute(np.absolute(ii-jj)-N)) # Centering the neighborhood function in the winner
                w[N - 2][jj,:] = w[N - 2][jj,:] + eta * A(dist,sigma) * (selectedInput - w[N - 2][jj,:]) # Updating the weights
        print(N,iterCount)
        iterCount = iterCount + 1 

elapsedTime = time.time() - t
```

In MATLAB, each iteration (each time the variable `iterCount` increases by 1) would be almost instant. In Python, each one takes a long time. I don't know why they are performing so different, but I would like to see if it is possible to speed up the Python version. Any suggestions?

EDIT: As requested in the comments, here is the much-faster MATLAB version of the code.

```
y = rand(2500,3) % Random dataset
A = @(d,s) exp(-d^2 / (2*s^2));
sigma_0 = 5;
eta_0 = 1;
iterMax = 250;
NMax = 10;
w = cell(NMax - 1,1);

%% KOHONEN 1D
tic();
for N = 2 : NMax 
    w{N - 1} = rand(N,size(y,2)) - 0.5;
    iterCount = 1; 
    while (iterCount < iterMax)
        mixInputs = y(randperm(size(y,1)),:);
        sigma = sigma_0 - (sigma_0/(iterMax + 1)) * iterCount;
        eta = eta_0 - (eta_0/(iterMax + 1)) * iterCount;
        for kk = 1 : size(mixInputs,1)
            input = mixInputs(kk,:);
            % [~,ii] = min(pdist2(input,w{N - 1}));
            aux = abs(repmat(input,N,1) - w{N - 1});
            [~,ii] = min((sum(aux.^2,2))); 
            for jj = 1 : N
                dist = min(abs(ii-jj) , abs(abs(ii-jj)-N));
                w{N - 1}(jj,:) = w{N - 1}(jj,:) + eta * A(dist,sigma) * (input - w{N - 1}(jj,:));
            end
        end
        N % Show N
        iterCount = iterCount + 1 % Show iterCount
    end
end
toc();
```

Comment: What versions of things are you using?  I'm on Python 3.4.5, getting the error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 19, in <module>
    w[N - 2] = np.random.uniform(0,1,(N,np.size(y,axis=1))) - 0.5 # Initial weights
`

Comment: @Prune I forgot to write that down, sorry. I'm using Python 2.7. I've added that information to the question, thanks!

Comment: Have you instrumented / profiled it at all? I'm running now, will provide analysis in an answer if I can. https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

Comment: @Attie No, I haven't (I didn't even know those words existed!). I'll check that link out and see what I can add to the question, thanks!

Comment: Put the main code in a function. Any code at top level uses a dictionary to stores its variables but code in a function uses indexes in an array.

Comment: Could you also post the Matlab code!?

Comment: @Cleb I've added it!

Comment: @DanD. Sorry for my ignorance, but I couldn't understand what you said. Are you saying to create a function that does all the tasks in the script I put above, and then call the function instead of running the script directly?

Comment: you can remove your kron - looks like it is taken care off by broadcasting: `aux = np.abs(selectedInput - np.array(w[N - 2]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick stab at some speedups - I think the output is the same, but for sure take some time to double check it:

```
import numpy as np
import time

np.random.seed(1234)
y = np.random.rand(2500,3) # Create random dataset to test

sigma_0 = float(5) # Initial standard deviation for A
eta_0 = float(1) # Initial learning rate
iterMax = 10 # Maximum number of iterations
NMax = 10 # Maximum number of neurons
w = {} # Initialize the size of the weight matrix (it will store NMax-2+1 sets of weights, each of varying size depending on the value of N)
#%% KOHONEN 1D
t = time.time() # Start time
for N in np.arange(2,NMax + 1): # Size of the network
    w[N - 2] = np.random.uniform(0,1,(N,np.size(y,axis=1))) - 0.5 # Initial weights
    iterCount = 1; # Iteration counter
    while iterCount < iterMax:
        # Mix the datapoints to choose them in random order
        mixInputs = y[np.random.permutation(np.size(y,axis = 0)),:]
        # Decrease the value of the variance and the learning rate
        sigma = sigma_0 - (sigma_0/(iterMax + 1)) * iterCount
        s2 = 2*sigma**2
        eta = eta_0 - (eta_0/(iterMax + 1)) * iterCount
        for kk in range(np.size(mixInputs,axis = 0)): # Picking one datapoint at a time
            selectedInput = mixInputs[kk,:]
            # These two lines calculate the weight that is the nearest to the datapoint selected
            aux = np.sum((selectedInput - np.array(w[N - 2]))**2, axis = -1)
            ii = np.argmin(aux)
            jjs = np.abs(ii - np.arange(N))
            dists = np.min(np.vstack([jjs , np.absolute(jjs-N)]), axis = 0)
            w[N - 2] = w[N - 2] + eta * np.exp((-dists**2)/s2).T[:,np.newaxis] * (selectedInput - w[N - 2]) # Updating the weights

        print(N,iterCount)
        iterCount = iterCount + 1 

elapsedTime = time.time() - t
```

Key speedups are mostly in using broadcasting to reduce loops/function calls.

we can replace the line:

```
 aux = np.absolute(np.array(np.kron(np.ones((N,1)),selectedInput)) - np.array(w[N - 2]))
```

with:

```
aux = np.abs(selectedInput - np.array(w[N - 2]))
```

(I have further crammed this in to a couple of the next steps). Numpy broadcasting gives us the same result, without have to take the kron product.

As an example:

```
np.kron(np.ones((3,1)), np.array([6,5,4])) - np.arange(-9,0).reshape(3,3)
```

is the same output as:

```
np.array([6,5,4]) - np.arange(-9,0).reshape(3,3)
```

`kron(np.ones(N,1),x)` gives an `N * x.shape[0]` array with N copies of x.
Broadcasting takes care of this in a much cheaper manner.

The other main speed up is to reduce the:

```
for jj in range(N):
```

To a matrix operation. We calculate the `2*sigma**2` once per loop, replace the A function with a native numpy call, and vectorize the rest.

Comment: Interesting... can you quantify the speedup? I'm also intrigued by the simplified `aux` assignment, if you would mind explaining further? - removing `kron()` would give a good boost...

Comment: for me it's about 1/3 the time as the original one. See the edit for a kron explanation

Comment: Hi, thank you for your detailed answer. I'm not getting the same result, though. In the line `ii= np.argmin(np.sum(selectedInput - np.array(w[N - 2])**2, axis = -1))`, the argument for `np.argmin()` does not return what I called `aux` in my script. Nevertheless, the boost is huge! I'm getting 21 seconds vs. my 54 seconds. However, I still don't understand why this is so slow compared to MATLAB (9 seconds), even with your improved version. Is there an explanation for such a difference?

Comment: Nice catch - I missed a bracket in there - with the new edit I get the exact same answer using the same seed. Not sure on the 9 vs 21 seconds, probably a complete rewrite would make it better. you can see there are some tricks with numpy - probably you know the matlab tricks.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful. One last question. In MATLAB, it is always better to vectorize things. What about Python? Is it advisable to avoid using loops, too? Or only if working with numpy?

Comment: You are writing python code with a strong Matlab accent :) numpy vectorization is good, but the way to speed your code in general is practice

Answer (score 2):

Use the [profiling module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) to find out what functions are being called, and how long they are taking.

In the output below, the columns have the following meanings:

> ncalls
>   for the number of calls,
>
> tottime
>   for the total time spent in the given function (and excluding time made in calls to sub-functions)
>
> percall
>   is the quotient of tottime divided by ncalls
>
> cumtime
>   is the cumulative time spent in this and all subfunctions (from invocation till exit). This figure is accurate even for recursive functions.
>
> percall
>   is the quotient of cumtime divided by primitive calls
>
> filename:lineno(function)
>   provides the respective data of each function

---

It looks like you're calling `A()` many, many times... often with the same value.

Output of `python2.7 -m cProfile -s tottime ${YOUR_SCRIPT}`

```
         5481855 function calls (5481734 primitive calls) in 4.986 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    1.572    1.572    4.986    4.986 x.py:1(<module>)
   214500    0.533    0.000    0.533    0.000 x.py:8(A)
   107251    0.462    0.000    1.986    0.000 shape_base.py:686(kron)
   107251    0.345    0.000    0.456    0.000 numeric.py:1015(outer)
   214502    0.266    0.000    0.563    0.000 {sorted}
...
```

Try caching the values:

```py
A_vals = {}

def A(d,s): # Neighborhood function
    t = (d,s)
    if t in A_vals:
        return A_vals[t]
    ret = np.exp(-d**2 / (2*s**2))
    A_vals[t] = ret
    return ret
```

Now we see:

```
         6206113 function calls (6205992 primitive calls) in 4.986 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    1.727    1.727    4.986    4.986 x.py:1(<module>)
   121451    0.491    0.000    2.180    0.000 shape_base.py:686(kron)
   121451    0.371    0.000    0.496    0.000 numeric.py:1015(outer)
   242902    0.293    0.000    0.621    0.000 {sorted}
   121451    0.265    0.000    0.265    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
...
   242900    0.091    0.000    0.091    0.000 x.py:7(A)
...
```

At this point it becomes a simple optimisation exercise!...

Next on your list is `kron()` - enjoy!

---

You'll also find it helpful (from a style point of view *and* profiling) to break your script into smaller functions. I've done the following purely for profiling reasons - so you would be better of using sensible names, and potentially making better segmentation.

```py
import numpy as np
import time

y = np.random.rand(2500,3) # Create random dataset to test

A_vals = {}
def A(d,s): # Neighborhood function
    t = (d,s)
    if t in A_vals:
        return A_vals[t]
    ret = np.exp(-d**2 / (2*s**2))
    A_vals[t] = ret
    return ret

def a():
    sigma_0 = float(5) # Initial standard deviation for A
    eta_0 = float(1) # Initial learning rate
    iterMax = 250 # Maximum number of iterations
    NMax = 10 # Maximum number of neurons
    w = range(NMax - 1) # Initialize the size of the weight matrix (it will store NMax-2+1 sets of weights, each of varying size depending on the value of N)
    #%% KOHONEN 1D
    t = time.time() # Start time
    for N in np.arange(2,NMax + 1): # Size of the network
        b(w, N, sigma_0, eta_0, iterMax)

    elapsedTime = time.time() - t

def b(w, N, sigma_0, eta_0, iterMax):
    w[N - 2] = np.random.uniform(0,1,(N,np.size(y,axis=1))) - 0.5 # Initial weights
    for iterCount in range(1, iterMax):
        c(N, sigma_0, eta_0, iterMax, iterCount, w)

def c(N, sigma_0, eta_0, iterMax, iterCount, w):
    # Mix the datapoints to choose them in random order
    mixInputs = y[np.random.permutation(np.size(y,axis = 0)),:]
    # Decrease the value of the variance and the learning rate
    sigma = sigma_0 - (sigma_0/(iterMax + 1)) * iterCount
    eta = eta_0 - (eta_0/(iterMax + 1)) * iterCount
    for kk in range(np.size(mixInputs,axis = 0)): # Picking one datapoint at a time
        d(N, w, mixInputs, sigma, eta, kk)
    print(N,iterCount)

def d(N, w, mixInputs, sigma, eta, kk):
    selectedInput = mixInputs[kk,:]
    # These two lines calculate the weight that is the nearest to the datapoint selected
    aux = np.absolute(np.array(np.kron(np.ones((N,1)),selectedInput)) - np.array(w[N - 2]))
    aux = np.sum(np.abs(aux)**2,axis=-1)
    ii = np.argmin(aux) # The node ii is the winner
    for jj in range(N):
        e(N, w, sigma, eta, selectedInput, ii, jj)

def e(N, w, sigma, eta, selectedInput, ii, jj):
    dist = min(np.absolute(ii-jj) , np.absolute(np.absolute(ii-jj)-N)) # Centering the neighborhood function in the winner
    f(N, w, sigma, eta, selectedInput, jj, dist)

def f(N, w, sigma, eta, selectedInput, jj, dist):
    w[N - 2][jj,:] = w[N - 2][jj,:] + eta * A(dist,sigma) * (selectedInput - w[N - 2][jj,:]) # Updating the weights

a()
```

```
         6701974 function calls (6701853 primitive calls) in 4.985 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   238921    0.691    0.000    0.777    0.000 x.py:56(f)
   119461    0.613    0.000    4.923    0.000 x.py:43(d)
   119461    0.498    0.000    2.144    0.000 shape_base.py:686(kron)
   238921    0.462    0.000    1.280    0.000 x.py:52(e)
   119461    0.369    0.000    0.495    0.000 numeric.py:1015(outer)
```

This identifies `f()` as the biggest time.

Comment: What is the difference between `tottime` and `cumtime`? Why did `tottime` for the module go up with your improvement? And why did the `cumtime` stay exactly the same?

Comment: Interesting question - I've updated the answer. I suspect the time distribution has shifted around due to the modifications, but I didn't expect that...

Comment: Hi Attie, thanks for your answer. As I commented in the answer by jeremycg, doing what you recommend here is of great help. However, MATLAB's version is still much faster, even though it is calling lots of functions too (the script is exactly the same, only the syntaxis changes). Why is this? And is there a way to achieve MATLAB's performance in Python for this specific piece of code?

Comment: @Tendero: As I understand it, Python's performance is still nowhere near MATLAB's. As long as everything is vectorized in Python you might not notice the difference much, but with loops and so on you would. If you want raw performance you need to either write compiled code that you call from Python (e.g. look into Cython or Pybind11), or move to a scripting language with a good JIT (e.g. look into Julia).

Comment: I can't comment on MATLAB, but I would presume that it compiles down to something much more efficient than Python - potentially with optimisations along the way. If you're after raw efficiency, then python isn't really the platform for you - it's possible to augment python with C functions fairly easily, which may provide the speed boost you're after...